# thread function is not called. Is there anything wrong with the syntax

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

The thread function "get_singleton" function is not called. I am not getting any error in my screen even.

```
class singleton{
private: singleton(){cout<<"constructor called";}
     singleton(singleton&);
     singleton& operator =(singleton &);
     ~singleton();

public: static singleton *s;
 static singleton* get_singleton();
 static pthread_mutex_t t;

};
pthread_mutex_t singleton::t=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
singleton* singleton::s=NULL;
singleton* singleton::get_singleton()
{
 cout<<"get_singleton called";
 if(s==NULL)
 {
    usleep(300);    
    s=new singleton();
 }

 return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int err;
 pthread_t t1,t2;
 err=pthread_create(&t1,NULL,(void *(*)(void *))singleton::get_singleton,NULL); 
 if(err!=0)
    cout<<"unable to create thread";
 err=pthread_create(&t2,NULL,(void *(*)(void *))singleton::get_singleton,NULL);
 if(err!=0)
    cout<<"unable to create thread";

 cout<<"end of func"<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Is there any error in the "pthread_create" api while calling "get_singleton" function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is likely exiting before your threads have even started. You need to join your threads before exiting main.

Use:

```
pthread_join(t1, NULL); // or nullptr if C++ >= 11, but then you could
pthread_join(t2, NULL); // use std::thread instead
```

Answer (score 1):

pthread_create expects a callback with the following signature:

```
void *(*start_routine) (void *)
```

You pass in a callback that returns a value. Won't that corrupt the stack? eg. the function pushes to the stack, but the caller never pops it because it expects nothing?

Comment: That signature has a (`void *`) return type, so no issue there.

Comment: I up-voted this answer because I had a similar problem with CreateThread with a start function that returned a value and was never called.  I removed the return value and it worked.